# IE8 Optimization Problems (Floated elements in <div>, Gradients in <header> ...)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I recently tested my browser in IE8, and it seems as though a lot of things are broken. Here is my site on a test server: [REDACTED]. If you use it in any up-to date browser, it will look fine. However, if you look at it in IE8 (Or IE10 in Compatibility Mode), there are a few problems.

1) The biggest problem is that the container doesn't work. I have a container class around certain elements that keep the content centered and at a fixed width, while also allowing the header/footer to go the full width of the screen. In IE8, the fixed width does not work.

CSS for the container

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-width: 916px;
}
```

And here is a sample of 1 of the times it is used in the HTML (in this example, the header. The PHP is for highlighting the current page in the menu).

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="float-left">
            <a href="/index.php" class="home"><img src="/Images/logo.png" id="logo" alt="logo" /></a>
        </div>

        <div class="float-right">
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="/index.php" <?php if (strpos($url, "index.php")) { echo " class='active'"; } ?> class="home">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/webgis.php" <?php if (strpos($url, "webgis.php")) { echo " class='active'"; } ?> id="gisnav">WEBGIS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/documents.php" <?php if (strpos($url, "documents.php")) { echo " class='active'"; } ?> id="docsnav">DOCUMENTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/statistics.php" <?php if (strpos($url, "statistics.php")) { echo " class='active'"; } ?> id="statsnav">STATISTICS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/support.php" <?php if (strpos($url, "support.php")) { echo " class='active'"; } ?> id="supportnav">SUPPORT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

I think the problem lies with either `margin: 0 auto;`, or with the floated elements inside the container, but I am not sure.

2) The header background is not longer the blue gradient I set it as. I'm not sure why this does not work since the gradient still works in the 3 `<div>`'s in the middle of the page.

Here is my CSS for the header

```
header {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;

    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #007dc1), color-stop(1, #0061a7));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#007dc1', endColorstr='#0061a7',GradientType=0);

    background-color:#007dc1;

    border:1px solid #124d77;

    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:700;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;

    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #154682;

    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And the HTML for the header is in Problem 1).

3) I changed the CSS for `<hr>` to make it a repeating image (It's just 3 pixels in a diagonal). IE8 doesn't seem to be showing this image properly. You can see what it is supposed to look like in any up-to date browser

Here is the CSS

```
hr {
    border: 0;
    background: url(/Images/tridots.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
    height: 5px;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

If this cannot be fixed, then it is no big deal. I can work around it

---

There are more problems, but I'm hoping they will resolve themselves when these get fixed. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) The container isn't working because you have a html comment before the DOCTYPE declaration. This is throwing IE8 into [quirks mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html).

Note: the w3c validator (http://validator.w3.org) will tell you this, as well as catch a couple other issues on your page. ;)

2.) IE8 doesn't understand html5 tags. You need to use something like Modernizr or html5shiv (etc). Or do something as simple as this: http://www.nickyeoman.com/blog/html/118-html5-tags-in-ie8. I think you'll find that your background colors appear.

3.) Not positive on this one ... but I think the above will fix this too.